# Test of string pattern match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to check if a string matches given pattern in JavaScript like

```
<script>
    var str = "Error: ...";
    var isMatch = checkMatch("^Error:*", str); //return a boolean
</script>
```

Is there any similar function doing this?

Comment: You can start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "Error: ...";
var has_match = str.match(/^Error:.*/) !== null
```